# Selenium - structuring all of the Objects into a Class

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, bots

So I made a selenium script that works - it changes the user-agent, and the proxy. For the Proxy, I added a function that tests if the proxy is alive, and if it's alive - the script runs - if not - then the script starts back at the top.

The only way I could think to call the whole script again if the test fails, is to make everything into a Class - and then call the Class again in the Else (fails) clause.

I'm new to actually making Classes, and some of the OOP principles.

```py
class Bot():
    def __init__():
        pass
    def useragent(self)
        random.choice
    def proxy(self)
        random.choice
        r=requests.get

        if r.status_code==200:
            run code
        else:
            Bot()
```

But now it just opens Chrome and then immediately closes it, throwing no errors.

Originally the script was laid out without a Class at all - no indenting, etc... and it worked perfectly - it just wouldn't check if the proxy is alive before passing it into the script.